# How do i make one window open at a time ? PYQT5

Tags: python, button, window, pyqt5, new-window

how can I make the code work in a way that when I click the proceed button, the 'select time' page appears but the calendar page hides?

As it appears that when I click the proceed button, both pages are open.

The expected output was that only one page opens at a time!!

My code :

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.title = "Select date from calendar"
        self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height = 600, 100, 500, 480
        self.iconName = "Ok.png"  # <--- home.png
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.iconName))
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.calendar = QCalendarWidget()
        self.calendar.setGridVisible(True)
        self.calendar.selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif", 10))
        self.label.setStyleSheet('color: blue;')

        self.proceedbutton = QPushButton("Proceed to select time", self)
        self.proceedbutton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")
        self.proceedbutton.setEnabled(False)
        self.proceedbutton.clicked.connect(self.window2)
        self.show()
        self.hide()

        self.backbutton = QPushButton("Back", self)
        self.backbutton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")

        self.comboBox = None

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.calendar, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.backbutton, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.proceedbutton, 2, 2, 1, 1)

    def window2(self):
        self.window.setWindowTitle("Select Time")
        self.window.setGeometry(self.left / 3, self.top, self.width / 3, self.height / 3)

        self.label = QLabel("Select Time")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.addItems(["choose time", "0700", "0800", "0900", "1000", "1100", "1200", "1300",
                                "1400", "1500","1600","1700","1800","1900","2000","2100", "2200"])
        self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onComboActivated)

        layout = QFormLayout(self.window)
        layout.addRow('Choose Time', self.comboBox)

        self.window.show()

    def onSelectionChanged(self):
        ca = self.calendar.selectedDate()
        self.label.setText(ca.toString())
        self.proceedbutton.setEnabled(True)

    def onComboActivated(self, text):
        print("choose time: {}".format(text))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A43dV.png)

Comment: using [QStackedWidget](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qstackedwidget.htm) you can replace widgets in current window.

Comment: @furas I've tried replacing it and run the program but, the calendar and proceed button disappears

Comment: but you have to do something more than only replacing it.

Comment: Could you guide me ob how I can do it? I'm very new to pyqt5.. @furas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses `QStackedWidget` to replace content in one window.

It has two functions to create two widgets with 
content - and they are put in stack `QStackedWidget`.

First it uses `self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)` to show widget with calendara and button which runs function with `self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)` to show widget with time. This widget also has button which runs again `self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)` to show again calendar.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height = 600, 100, 500, 480

        self.page1 = self.create_page1()
        self.page2 = self.create_page2()

        self.stack = QStackedWidget()
        self.stack.addWidget(self.page1)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.page2)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.stack)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.show_page1()

        self.show()


    def create_page1(self):
        page = QWidget()
        #self.iconName = "Ok.png"  # <--- home.png
        #self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.iconName))

        page.calendar = QCalendarWidget(page)
        page.calendar.setGridVisible(True)
        page.calendar.selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

        page.label = QLabel(page)
        #page.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif", 10))
        page.label.setStyleSheet('color: blue;')

        page.proceedbutton = QPushButton("Proceed to select time", page)
        page.proceedbutton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")
        page.proceedbutton.setEnabled(False)
        page.proceedbutton.clicked.connect(self.show_page2)

        page.backbutton = QPushButton("Back", page)
        page.backbutton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")

        page.comboBox = None

        page.grid = QGridLayout(page)
        page.grid.addWidget(page.calendar, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        page.grid.addWidget(page.label, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        page.grid.addWidget(page.backbutton, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        page.grid.addWidget(page.proceedbutton, 2, 2, 1, 1)

        return page

    def create_page2(self):
        page = QWidget()

        layout = QFormLayout(page)

        page.comboBox = QComboBox(page)
        page.comboBox.addItems(["choose time", "0700", "0800", "0900", "1000", "1100", "1200", "1300",
                                "1400", "1500","1600","1700","1800","1900","2000","2100", "2200"])
        page.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onComboActivated)
        layout.addRow('Choose Time', page.comboBox)

        page.proceedbutton = QPushButton("Back", page)
        page.proceedbutton.clicked.connect(self.show_page1)
        layout.addRow(page.proceedbutton)

        return page

    def show_page1(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Select date from calendar")
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def show_page2(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Select Time")
        self.setGeometry(self.left / 3, self.top, self.width / 3, self.height / 3)
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def onSelectionChanged(self):
        ca = self.page1.calendar.selectedDate()
        self.page1.label.setText(ca.toString())
        self.page1.proceedbutton.setEnabled(True)

    def onComboActivated(self, text):
        print("choose time: {}".format(text))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: [example which uses StackedLayout](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pyqt5/change-content-using-stack/main-stack-pages.py) and it keep every page as separated class.